# Debian Extending Primary (root) partition without data loss

Tags: partition, size

I have a VM with Debian installed on it. I want to extend the primary partition without losing data.

Here is output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 34.2 GiB, 36700160000 bytes, 71680000 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0eacd5f2

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 46139391 46137344  22G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       46141438 52426751  6285314   3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       46141440 52426751  6285312   3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot your VM system off a LiveCD ISO that includes gparted (or install gparted on a live distro after it is booted), and then you can manipulate your partitions to your hearts desire via a friendly GUI.

If your drive isn't big enough, you can extend it using your VM system's tools first.

*Unrelated helpful comment: you should delete your swap partition - these are counterproductive on VMs*

Comment: thanks, what about the extended partition? what is that responsible for? can i delete it?

Comment: GParted is an effective and easy way to extend the disks. But leave your swap partition as is! it's not counterproductive to have on VMs at all! You've got an extended partition, it wouldn't be necessary for 2 partitions only. Apparently your swap part resides inside extended part. So don't delete them! Unless you delete swap, then delete extended part, and afterwards make a new primary swap part.

Comment: You extended partition seems to hold you swap file and I would guess your home directory as well. It can have any number of things mounted on it, that is up to your fstab file; you can have a look at your fstab file to see what is mounted where.

Comment: @krackout Swapping is NOT necessary for a VM, and can in some cases be a performance hindrance. I recommend deleting the partition. Besdies you can always create a swapfile later if you need to. Read this old document for an in-depth explantion: https://www.dell.com/community/VMware/Best-Practices-for-VM-Swap-File-Locations-and-Guest-OS-Page/td-p/6921765

Comment: @Octavian Since the size of the extended partition is just 3G and the swap partition covers all of it, the home directory must be contained within the root filesystem. So in this case, it is possible to delete and recreate the entire extended partition if necessary to allow the extension. Also, the document in the link does *not* recommend removing swap, in fact it offers various strategies on managing swap on VMware, even though "if you are actually swapping you're in trouble". But there are different grades of trouble, and the "hitting a brick wall" behavior with no swap can be worse.

Comment: @Octavian It mostly depends on how easily you can get extra resources: if you need to show a measurable downward trend in response time at peak load before your boss authorizes extra memory, you will need some swap so that the trend will be visible before the application starts crashing. So it might be called "swap for human factor reasons." :-/

Comment: @Octavian. You are completely wrong regarding swap. Swap is needed, as tecloM mentioned, if you are out of RAM, your app will crash. It has nothing to do whether the app runs on VM or physical. In the link you send, the discussion is about vmware swap of each VM, for ESXi use. It has nothing to do with swap inside the VM. Even about ths kind of swap, there are other suggestions, live moving it to another datastore, not deleting it. Please be better informed and stop insisting on swap not being necessary.

Comment: OK, well thats true as long as you are overcommiting memory. However as long as you are not overcomitting memory, then you are better off not using swap.   https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.resmgmt.doc/GUID-AC40823A-695B-438A-A8F2-4B7C51A0D014.html